# data range transformation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of objects that is being returned from service call.

```
Object has below attributes:
DateVal1
DateVal2
Value
```

How do I assign object to range as 2D matrix range:
Date1 as column, Date2 as header row

If there is object with row,column combination print value else print NA.

Data can be large (Max 30x30) so trying to avoid lookup in list every time.

```
Date     1/31/2015 2/28/2015 3/31/2015
1/1/2015 1         NA         NA
1/2/2015 NA        2          NA
1/3/2015 NA        NA         3
```

What if this is slight different?

```
 Object has below attributes:
    DateVal1
    DateVal2
    Value1
    Value2
```

And desired o/p is this:

```
Date1     Date2             110        20         30
1/1/2015  1/10/2015          1         NA         NA
1/2/2015  1/20/2015         NA         2          NA
1/3/2015  1/31/2015         NA         NA         3
```

Comment: Don't use `Date` as variable, since it's predefined function, returning current date.

Comment: I have updated ref code.

Comment: You can use a couple of scripting dictionary objects to map dates to column/row numbers.  Are the column/row headers pre-defined, or are you populating them from the list (array?) of objects?

Comment: Row/col headers arent predefined. They need to be populated based on object values. So dynamic

Comment: Are the objects in the array sorted in any way?

Comment: Not sorted. But I can do a sort after service call by attribute Date1 or Date2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim points, i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim dictRows, dictCols, grid(0, 0)
    'dictionary to map "key" values to row numbers
    Set dictRows = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'dictionary to map "key" values to column numbers
    Set dictCols = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    points = getPoints()
    r = 0
    c = 0

    '[sort points by date1 here]
    'map date1 to "row"
    For i = LBound(points) To UBound(points)
        If Not dictRows.exists(points(i).date1) Then
            r = r + 1
            dictRows.Add points(i).date1, r
        End If
    Next i
    '[sort points by date2 here]
    'map date2 to "column"
    For i = LBound(points) To UBound(points)
        If Not dictCols.exists(points(i).date2) Then
            c = c + 1
            dictCols.Add points(i).date2, c
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim grid(1 To r, 1 To c)

    For i = LBound(points) To UBound(points)
        grid(dictRows(points(i).date1), dictCols(points(i).date2)) = points(i).Value
    Next i

    'populate on worksheet
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A2").Resize(r, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dictRows.keys)
        .Range("B2").Resize(r, c).Value = grid
        .Range("B1").Resize(1, c).Value = dictCols.keys
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That is perfect. I will post the tested version of it. Many thanks.

Comment: What if I have slight different object structure? Date1,Date2,Val1,Val2? I have edited question. or that needs separate question?

Comment: Try adapting the example I wrote, and post a new question with your code if you run into problems.

Comment: That was helpful. I just created dict using concated dates. I will update my answer for both scenarios.